# SQL Server Check Constraints on a column and a value in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table

```
PKID    FID     RESULT
======================
1       1       1
2       1       2 
3       1       2 
4       1       3 
4       2       1 
4       2       1
```

I'm trying to set a constraint so that I can't insert into the table another record with **FID  = 1** if there already exists a record with **FID = 1 and RESULT = 3**.

I've tried to create a function like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION MyCheck
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @FID int
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT  PKID FROM MyTable WHERE (RESULT= 3) AND (FID= @FID))
        return 1
    return 0
END
```

but when I create the constraint using this function:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
    WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Code
    CHECK (MyCheck(FID) = 0)
```

I get this error:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint
>   "CK_Code". The conflict occurred in database "MyDB", table "MyTable",
>   column 'FID'.

Comment: Yes, IT's INT. PKID, FID and RESULTS are INT. PKID is primary key, FID is a foreign key

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the update/clarification, yes, we now have to use triggers<sup>1</sup>. We can no longer be declarative because there's no way to look at a set of data, say:

```
FID     RESULT
==============
1       1
1       3 
1       2 
1       2 
2       1 
2       1
```

And to decide whether that data should be legitimate or not. It *is* legitimate if the `(1,3)` row was the last row inserted. It's *not* legitimate if any of the other rows for FID `1` was the last row inserted.

So, a trigger it is then:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_PreventBadInsert
ON MyTable
AFTER INSERT
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF EXISTS(select * from inserted i inner join MyTable m
                 on i.PK <> m.PK and i.FID = m.FID
                    and m.Result = 3)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Cannot insert a new row once one row has result 3',16,1);
        ROLLBACK;
    END
```

Note that this will abort the entire `INSERT` statement if one row violates the requirement. It will also abort an `INSERT` that attempts to add two rows for the same `FID` where *one* of the rows has a `RESULT` of 3.

We probably also want to write an update trigger that either prohibits the changing of `FID` values for any existing rows or performs a similar check to the above, but I don't know what your requirement is there.

<strike>If you're on SQL Server 2008 or later, just a filtered index should work:</strike>

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_Max1Result3 ON MyTable (FID) WHERE Result = 3
```

(And your function/check doesn't work because there's nothing in there to prevent a row from picking up itself as the "existing" row)

---

<sup>1</sup> Have is a strong word. There may be other ways but I think the trigger is probably the most straightforward approach.

Comment: Thanks Damien. It works. Altough in table design mode the index doesn't show the filter

Comment: @AlinI - the design tools always seem to be buggy and behind the times with features. Most people abandon using them sooner or later.

Comment: After further testing I realized that this solution does not do all that I require. I need to prevent entering another record containing FID = 1, what ever value would result have, if there is already a record FID = 1 AND Result = 3.......

Comment: That will be trickier to achieve since now there's a temporal aspect to it. I.e. non `Result`=3 rows which are currently in the table, if you were to delete them and attempt to re-insert them, would now be rejected. I'll have to have a think about this. Are you sure this data model is actually the best way to approach your problem?

Comment: this is all I could think. I don't need to delete old records. if I would need to re-add old deleted records, then i can do with having to re-add that one record... The end point is to prevent adding more records that have FID = 1 when I already have that one record containing also Result = 3. Maybe I could use Triggers?

Comment: Is this trigger 100% efficient?

Answer (score 1):

your code is absolutely fine.
just alter you function,

```
Alter FUNCTION dbo.MyCheck
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @FID int
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    IF  (SELECT  count(PKID) FROM tmp WHERE (RESULT= 3) AND (FID= @FID))>1
        return 1
    return 0
END
```

also note that first check your data if you already have duplicate record.if you have already duplicate data voilating your constraint then you cannot create constraint.

run,

> select fid from table where result=3 group by fid having count(fid)>1

if you get rows then you need deleting it .